# A simple float addition produces a false result

Tags: c

These numbers add up to zero, but the code puts out 18 as the result.
For my task its required that the numbers are defined as floats.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {


float b1 = 23.0;   
float b2 = 42.0;
float b3 = 2073741824.0;
float b4 = -2073741714.0;
float b5 = -64.0;
float b6 = -111.0;
float be;

be = b1+b2+b3+b4+b5+b6;

printf("Das Float Ergebnis ist:   %f\n", be);

return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: you're running into a range issue with `floats`

Comment: Step 1: ` b1+b2+b3+b4+b5+b6` --> ` b1+b2+(b3+b4)+b5+b6`

Comment: If you use double instead of float, you should have enough precision for these numbers (float makes little sense when memory isn't an issue).

Comment: `-2073741714.0` is not typically _exactly_ representable as a `float`.  Use a wider types or accept imprecision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-2073741714.0` is not typically *exactly* representable as a `float`.  Use wider types or accept imprecision.  `float` as a 32-bit variable can not exactly encode *every number*, just about 2<sup>32</sup> of them. The typical closest one is `-2073741696`

```
float b4 = -2073741714.0;
printf("b4 = %f\n", b4);
// typical output
// b4 = -2073741696.000000
```

Instead consider either wider  FP types.

```
int main(void) {
  double b1 = 23.0;
  double b2 = 42.0;
  double b3 = 2073741824.0;
  double b4 = -2073741714.0;
  double b5 = -64.0;
  double b6 = -111.0;
  double be;
  printf("b4 = %f\n", b4);

  be = b1 + b2 + (b3 + b4) + b5 + b6;
  printf("Das Float Ergebnis ist:   %f\n", be); // Das Float Ergebnis ist:   0.000000
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Or use wider math

```
int main(void) {
  float b1 = 23.0;
  float b2 = 42.0;
  float b3 = 2073741824.0;
  double b4 = -2073741714.0;
  float b5 = -64.0;
  float b6 = -111.0;
  float be;
  printf("b4 = %f\n", b4);

  be = b1 + b2 + (b3 + b4) + b5 + b6;
  printf("Das Float Ergebnis ist:   %f\n", be); // Das Float Ergebnis ist:   0.000000
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

A 3rd choice is to re-arrange the evaluation order.  This will help, yet not overcome limitations of `float`.

```
int main(void) {
  float b1 = 23.0;
  float b2 = 42.0;
  float b3 = 2073741824.0;
  float b4 = -2073741714.0;
  float b5 = -64.0;
  float b6 = -111.0;
  float be;

  be = b1 + b2 + (b3 + b4) + b5 + b6;
  printf("Das Float Ergebnis ist:   %f\n", be);  // Das Float Ergebnis ist:   18.000000
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Some will argue that the exact width of a float is unspecified by the `C standard` and therefore implementation-dependent, but on any platform you are likely to encounter a `C float` means an [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) [single-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) number.

It's a lot of math over there if you are interested, but, in a nutshell, a `float` can store about `7-8 significant decimal digits`. Let me illustrate this with an example:

```
2073741824.0; // float
       ^^^ ^ // all this information is most likely lost
```

By **most likely** I mean that you should **NEVER** assume that the program will remeber those digits.

```
2073741xxx.x; // float
       ^^^ ^ // this is how you should treat you number form a safe programmer's prespective
```

Comment: Thank you for the excelent explanation. This was not mentioned in any tutorial i read.

Comment: "float can store about 7-8 significant decimal digits" is an OK approximation.   [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) has, at worst, 6 significant decimal digits (research `FLT_DIG`).  6-9 would be a better generalization.